# wrong page load with local apache on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache2

On /etc/hosts I created a localhost domain called drupaltest. On /home/user/Documents I copied my drupaltest backup. On /etc/apache2/sites-available I created a file named drupaltest which points to the directory I created. Finally I restarted apache2.

But if I call the drupaltest domain in a browser I got the default apache message 'It works!'.

Other drupal instances I installed run well. Except the one I copied.

Do I have to do addtional things?

Answer (score 0):

Creating the virtual host is `sites-available` is not enough. You also need to enable it. That can be done using the following command:

```
sudo a2ensite drupaltest
```

Considering that the file in `sites-available` is called `drupaltest`

Next you need to restart, or at least reload, apache.

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```